# UIImageView dragging jerky when used in Screencapture view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I am working in a project where I need to drag the images and create the video for the same,
it works fine when I use it in the main view.

I use `ScreencaptureView.h` and `ScreencaptureView.m` file for video recording, I subview it in my main view and add subview the image object in the capture view.

Now the problem is because I subview the image in  the `ScreencaptureView` the dragging becomes slow.

What could be done to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe try rasterizing if it has shadows and other layer effects...

Comment: I think it is because of handling two events in touch actions, can you put some code  ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

- during touch began event, first, add the view being dragged to root view as subview. call
  bringSubviewToFront method to keep the dragged view top of the root view hierarchy.
- Make sure the root view should be a parent for both dragged view and 
  target view(ScreencaptureView in your case).
- during touch end event add the dragged view to the target view(ScreencaptureView).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprise that it slows down your animation. The amount of data to capture and save to memory as images is huge. No miracle here. The data have to be flushed from your graphic memory to the RAM and then to disk and that takes a long time. What I recommend to you is to do it in 2 steps. The main idea is to capture the less data as you can when you are in real time.

**- step 1 : CAPTURE IN REAL TIME**

Don't put your subviews in ScreencaptureView for this step but in a normal view or disable the capture if the option is available.
Capture only the translation values you make on each image in a dictionary for example where the keys refers to your images (NSValue with pointer to your image). Save one dictionary per frame. Then you have an array of dictionaries. You can imagine other solutions to store your dumped datas.
You can do it easily at 30 fps or 60 fps.
That way your capture is very lightweight and the animation will be totally smooth for the user.

**-step 2 : REPLAY - POST-PROCESSING**

Now you can put your subviews in ScreencaptureView or if already simply activate the capture mode.
Replay your animation by reading you recorded values and re-apply the corresponding translations to the images (you have to keep them of course) and capture the frames as usual. Now it can be slower but it does not matter. The frame will be processed one by one.

This is done ! You have now a smooth video screenshot of your animation.

Is it clear ?

Comment: Hi this makes sense, but I've found that it doesn't work with animations, so on screen you get smooth motion tweens, but the video essentially only records the keyframes, just wondering if you have any advice with this?